# DataTables - hide buttons on second page

Tags: jquery, html, button, datatables, hide

I try to hide buttons in my table when certain value is not "error".

It works perfectly fine on the first page, but due to pagination the buttons are not hidden on the second page.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c5aveL6/)

```
$(function() {
$('#table1').each(function() {
var Cell = $(this).find('td:eq(2)');
debugger;
if (Cell.text() !== 'error' ) {
$(this).find('button').hide();
       }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you have done with the `initComplete` callback, you can pass a `drawCallback` function through the DataTable options. This will run everytime the table is drawn. Just add the following to the options.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71L9L24e/)

See: https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback

```
drawCallback: function (settings) {
    $('#table1').each(function () {
        var Cell = $(this).find('td:eq(2)');
        debugger;
        if (Cell.text() !== 'error') {
            $(this).find('button').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the function when the page change. If you inspect the table you can see all rows not been loaded.